# mongoDB Time-field Trigger?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a node based back-end that integrates with a mongoDb instance. The DB has a collection of calendar events, each with a unique date-time field. I am trying to consider the best way to perform a reminder function 15 minutes before the set time.

The only idea i have come up with is to consistently query the DB with setInterval and run the function then. Is there a better way?

Comment: Are the events dynamic (i.e. can the `date-time` field change) or are they static?

Comment: They can change but most are static.

Comment: Are you not thinking to use any Delayed queue solution? Since this is classic problem of delayed queue. You will get better solution instead of queries mongodb consistently, You need to just push to delay queue while you are inserting on calendar event collection with proper calculation of delay time.

Comment: you can also try `cron-job` then run every 15 minuts

Answer (score 2):

Obviously `setInterval` and pulling the database seems to be the easiest approach. Below solution can be considered as an alternative where the database initiates those scheduled events so you will get **push** instead of pull approach.

Let's say you have simple collection **scheduledEvents** which contains one field **scheduledAt** of type **ISODate**, for instance:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c457cb554651d56ffe0c759"), "scheduledAt" : ISODate("2019-01-21T08:03:01.129Z") }
```

Then you can create [TTL index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-ttl/) on that collection. Basically the idea is that MongoDB database server will be periodically removing those documents when **scheduledAt** becomes a date from the past.

```
db.scheduledEvents.createIndex( { "scheduledAt": 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 30} )
```

Behind the curtain there is a scheduled job that is running on the database server which queries and removes all those documents. The documents won't get removed immediately - there is a slight delay but it should be acceptable for you.

Now you have a mechanism for scheduling so all you need to do is to subscribe to those events from your code. To do that you can take advantage of [Change Streams](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/changeStreams/index.html).

To use them you have to run your db as replica set (can be [standalone replica set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/convert-standalone-to-replica-set/)). Then in your application code you can subscribe to **scheduledEvents** collection using below code:

```
const changeStreamCursor = db.scheduledEvents.watch();

function pollStream(cursor) {
    while (!cursor.isExhausted()) {
        if (cursor.hasNext()) {
            var change = cursor.next();
            if(change.operationType === "delete"){
                // your logic goes here
            }
        }
    }
    pollStream(cursor);
}

pollStream(changeStreamCursor);
```

Obviously `scheduledEvents` collection can contain other fields related to your business logic and those can be accessed inside your change stream listener.

Comment: This approach will need additional efforts.  It asked for a 15 minutes reminder, and therefore you can't use scheduleAt for the TTL index.  Besides, for this to work, the document has to be deleted to create the oplog event.  You have to set the scheduleAt 15 minutes before the event and remove the event to make TTL work.

Answer (score -1):

Polling from database is the simplest way.  If your concern is to avoid querying database too frequently, you can try the following.

1. Start the node based back-end.
2. Look for the first future calendar event.
3. Use setInterval() to schedule next reminder.
4. After reminder event is triggered, repeat from #2.

If your events are updated, you can use MongoDB's [Change Streams](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/changeStreams/) to monitor changes.  Once a calendar event is updated, compare it to the next reminder event, and if it's before the next calendar reminder, replace the next reminder.

Hope this helps.