# How to schedule an event based on database document date field (Node.js + MongoDB)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, nestjs

I have a web server written in NestJS that allows users to create auctions.
Every auction document has an `end_date` field.
I want to schedule an event when the `end_date` has reached.

Is there a way to schedule or trigger a function when the time has reached in MongoDB or Node.js?
Is this even a good approach to react to date expiration events?

Comment: Here is another question that can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54201066/mongodb-time-field-trigger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd generally recommend lifting off this kind of work to external services that are dedicated to handling these operations.

Take a look at

https://cloud.google.com/tasks

It is a nice way to schedule tasks in an external queue. When the "trigger_date" is reached, google will trigger an HTTP request to an endpoint you defined. From there you can implement your own logic.

If off-lifting is no option, building your own queue could be a nice project as well.